# LibGDX: How to keep displaying actor after drag (drag off)

Tags: drag-and-drop, libgdx

I have implemented drag and drop, but the problem is after user releases the drag. The dragged actor is dissapear from the screen. How to move actor to its new location or return to its location if it is dropped not in its proper locations?

Thanks for your answers.

Regards,

Alfa
'

```
final DragAndDrop dragAndDrop = new DragAndDrop();
  final Box sourceBox =  boxList.get(0);
  final Box targetBox =  boxHolderList.get(0);

  Source source = new Source(sourceBox) {

     @Override
     public void dragStop(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
           int pointer, Payload payload, Target target) {

        Box sourceBox = (Box) payload.getDragActor();
        if (target == null){
           sourceBox.setPosition(sourceBox.getX(), sourceBox.getY());
        }
        else{
           Box targetBox = (Box) target.getActor();
           sourceBox.setPosition(targetBox.getX(), targetBox.getY());
        }
     }

     @Override
     public Payload dragStart(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {

        dragAndDrop.setDragActorPosition(-1*sourceBox.getWidth()/2, 1*sourceBox.getHeight()/2);
        Payload payload = new Payload();
        payload.setDragActor(sourceBox);

        Label validLabel = new Label("Valid!", skin);
        validLabel.setColor(0, 1, 0, 1);
        payload.setValidDragActor(validLabel);

        Label invalidLabel = new Label("Invalid!", skin);
        invalidLabel.setColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        payload.setInvalidDragActor(invalidLabel);

        return payload;
     }


  };
```

Answer (score 0):

this drag and drop method is quite mesh, you may try this

```
 yourActor.addListener(new DragListener(){

        public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
            yourActor.moveBy(x-yourActor.getWidth()/2,y-yourActor.getHeight()/2);
        }});
```